# Problems with IQueryable generic types -- Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type 'X'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to build a repository that takes a generic type and returns a generic IQueryable. I have it running when the data source is a db table. I want to do the same thing when the data source is an XML document, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(this.url);

    IQueryable<T> nodes = null;
    nodes = (
    from c in xml.Nodes().Cast<T>()
    select c).AsQueryable<T>();

    return nodes;
}
```

Here's the error (which by the way occurs at runtime, not compile):

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type 'X'

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast the `XElement` to `T`, not it's *Value*.  You should be able to use:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll() where T : IConvertible
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(this.url);

    var nodes = xml.Nodes().Select(xe => Convert.ChangeType(xe.Value, typeof(T))).Cast<T>();
    return nodes.AsQueryable();
}
```

This works by extracting the value as a string, and using Convert to (attempt) to map it to the specified type. This would require the type `T` to implement [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so I also added that constraint.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yeah - realized there would be a failure in general, so falling back to Convert.ChangeType on the string value.

Comment: Doesn't change much. Still custom conversion `string` to `T` is necessary. And by getting `Value` only you're loosing the document structure. I would say, it's better to define `(MyClass)XElement` conversion than `(MyClass)string`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes, it requires IConvertible to be implemented. Added this to comments in answer text.  I don't believe there's a way around that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a solution which would *automagically* translate XML document into your custom class? There is nothing like that.

Possible solutions:

Prepare an interface with conversion method and use that method to convert `XElement` to your class instances:

```
public interface IXEntity<T>
{
    T GetEntity(XElement source);
}

public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>(IXEntityFactory<T> factory)
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(this.url);

    var nodes = xml.Elements().Select(xe => factory.GetEntity(xe));
    return nodes.AsQueryable();
}
```

or extend your method to get conversion delegate:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>(Func<XElement, T> projection)
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(this.url);

    var nodes = xml.Elements().Select(xe => projection(xe));
    return nodes.AsQueryable();
}
```

btw. I have no idea why you're trying to use `IQueryable<T>`. LINQ to XML uses `IEnumerable<T>` anyway, so there is no difference between version with `AsEnumerable()` and without that call.

Comment: Ah, this gave me the insight I needed to solve my dilemma. **Prepare an interface with conversion method and use that method to convert XElement to your class instances**